# Synchronous "Ajax" Call with Jquery does not appear to Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flux

I'm pretty new to javascript and I'm buiding a react/flux app and using jquery to make synchronous "ajax" calls (sjax?) to the backend. I'm getting inconsistent behavior because (I think) my ajax call is not blocking despite using async:false. The key code snips are below.

The execution flow starts in the Flux store with the ActionTypes.LOGIN case, then moves to fetchAccount(action.value);, and should be synchronously followed by AppStore.emitChange();

The issue is if I call AppStore.emitChange(); in my $.ajax success function then I am able to guarantee that AppStore.emitChange(); come after the success function, but otherwise if AppStore.emitChange() comes after the fetchAccount(action.value) call it gets executed before the $.ajax success function completes.

In my Flux Store, I call a helper function and then emit a change:

```
// Register callback to handle all updates
AppDispatcher.register(function(action) {
  var text;

  switch(action.actionType) {
    case ActionTypes.LOGIN:
      fetchAccount(action.value);
      //if i put AppStore.emitChange(); here it's invoked 
      //before fetchAccount completes even though the $.ajax call is async: false
      AppStore.emitChange();
      break;

   //... code ommitted ...
  }
});
```

My helper function executes the ajax call:

```
function fetchAccount(email) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://www.foo.com/api/accounts/" + email,
    jsonp: "callback",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    headers: {"Accept" : "application/javascript; charset=utf-8"},
    success: function(data) {
      user = data;
      currentViewState = AppStates.CONTENT_VIEW;
      //AppStore.emitChange(); ---> if i emitChange here it works
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
      user = "";
      currentViewState = AppStates.LOGIN_VIEW;

    }    
  });
};
```

Comment: Never use `async: false`; it's terrible practice. You really should refactor your code to work with the async event handlers provided by the `$.ajax` method.

Comment: Np, I'll read up and change it. What's the issue with async: false?

Comment: The issue is because it locks the UI thread, so the browser window does not update while the request is being made. This looks to the user like the browser has crashed, when its actually just waiting for a response from the server before updating.

Comment: hmm, i'm not sure how to adapt this to use the async handlers. I think i just need to use ajaxComplete but i only see how to attach that to dom elements.

Comment: From your basic code same, it looks like you just need to call `emitChange()` from within the `success` handler, passing `data` and `AppStates.CONTENT_VIEW` as parameters: `AppStore.emitChange(data, AppStates.CONTENT_VIEW);`

Comment: Yea, that's how I solved it but I didn't want my emit change calls to get spread throughout my code. I wanted them all called in the same place. I think maybe I'll just have to pass the emit change function into my fetch account function.

Answer (score 1):

Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/